# Replace Image in an placeholder inside generated PPT using PPTX4j

Tags: java, powerpoint, docx4j

@JasonPlutext,

Hi Jason! I tried the above code but it just replaces an totally the image deleting the whole template.

I would like to just replace/add a particular relationship of the image ,say

```
 <Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="../media/image10.png"/>
```

in place of rId8 i would like to replace rId7 image.

My Source Code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 String inputfilepath = "C:\\Users\\saranyac\\QUERIES\\Estimation\\PPT-PSR\\PSR_Dev0ps\\PSRAutomationTemplate.pptx";

 PresentationMLPackage presentationMLPackage =           (PresentationMLPackage)OpcPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));

     MainPresentationPart pp = presentationMLPackage.getMainPresentationPart();

      SlidePart slidePart = presentationMLPackage.getMainPresentationPart().getSlide(0);

        SlideLayoutPart layoutPart = slidePart.getSlideLayoutPart();

        System.out.println("SlidePart Name:::::"+slidePart.getPartName().getName());

        String layoutName = layoutPart.getJaxbElement().getCSld().getName(); 

        System.out.println("layout: " + layoutPart.getPartName().getName() + " with cSld/@name='" + layoutName + "'");

        System.out.println("Master: " + layoutPart.getSlideMasterPart().getPartName().getName());

        System.out.println("layoutPart.getContents()::::::::s: " + layoutPart.getContents());

        //layoutPart.setContents(   (SldLayout)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(SAMPLE_PICTURE, Context.jcPML));


        // Add image part
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\saranyac\\PPT-PSR\\PSR_Dev0ps\\ppt\\media\\image10.png" );
        BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart 
            = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(presentationMLPackage, slidePart, file);

                   Relationship rel = pp.getRelationshipsPart().getRelationshipByID("rId8");    
     System.out.println("Relationship:::::::s: " +imagePart.getSourceRelationship().getId());

      // pp.removeSlide(rel);
       java.util.HashMap<String, String>mappings = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();

        mappings.put("rId8", imagePart.getSourceRelationship().getId());

         String outputfilepath = "C:\\Work\\24Jan2018_CheckOut\\PPT-TRAILS\\Success.pptx";
        //presentationMLPackage.save(new java.io.File(outputfilepath));

        SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(presentationMLPackage);
        saver.save(outputfilepath);

        System.out.println("\n\n done .. saved " + outputfilepath);

    }
```

Please help me how to replace an image in the generated PPT.

With Regards,
Saranya

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Can you please suggest me any idea?I'm getting below error,Exception in thread "main" org.pptx4j.Pptx4jException: No slide is the target of that relationship.

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Please be so kind and throw some light on me . I'm completely dependedent on some suggestion. I was hoping that  Relationship rel = pp.getRelationshipsPart().getRelationshipByID("rId8");    
     System.out.println("Relationship:::::::s: " +imagePart.getSourceRelationship().getId());

      // pp.removeSlide(rel);     would work..Appreciate your needy help!

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/pptx4j/org/pptx4j/samples/TemplateReplaceSimple.java (just added):

```
package org.pptx4j.samples;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.docx4j.TraversalUtil;
import org.docx4j.TraversalUtil.CallbackImpl;
import org.docx4j.dml.CTBlip;
import org.docx4j.dml.CTBlipFillProperties;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.PresentationMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PresentationML.SlidePart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.BinaryPartAbstractImage;
import org.pptx4j.Pptx4jException;

/**
 * Example of how to replace text and images in a Pptx.
 * 
 * Text is replaced using the familiar VariableReplace approach.
 * 
 * Images are replaced by replacing their byte content.
 * 
 * @author jharrop
 *
 */
public class TemplateReplaceSimple {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Docx4JException, Pptx4jException, JAXBException, IOException {

        // Input file
        String inputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sample-docs/pptx/image.pptx";

        // String replacements
        HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mappings.put("colour", "green");

        // Image replacements
        List<ImageReplacementDetails>  imageReplacements = new ArrayList<ImageReplacementDetails>();

        ImageReplacementDetails example1 = new ImageReplacementDetails();
        example1.slideIndex = 0;
        example1.imageRelId = "rId2";
        example1.replacementImageBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("test.png"));
        imageReplacements.add(example1);



        PresentationMLPackage presentationMLPackage = 
                (PresentationMLPackage)OpcPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));


        // First, the text replacements
        List<SlidePart> slideParts= 
                presentationMLPackage.getMainPresentationPart().getSlideParts();
        for (SlidePart slidePart : slideParts) {

            slidePart.variableReplace(mappings);
        }


        // Second, the image replacements.
        // We have a design choice here.  
        // Either we can replace text placeholders with images,
        // or we can replace existing images with new images, but keep the XML specifying size etc
        // Here I opt for the latter, so what we need is the relId and image bytes.
        for( ImageReplacementDetails ird : imageReplacements) {

            // its a bit inefficient to potentially traverse a single slide
            // multiple times, but I've done it this way to keep this example simple
            SlidePart slidePart= 
                    presentationMLPackage.getMainPresentationPart().getSlide(ird.slideIndex);

            SlidePicFinder traverser = new SlidePicFinder();
            new TraversalUtil(slidePart.getJaxbElement().getCSld().getSpTree().getSpOrGrpSpOrGraphicFrame(), traverser);

            for(org.pptx4j.pml.Pic pic : traverser.pics) {

                CTBlipFillProperties  blipFill = pic.getBlipFill();
                if (blipFill!=null) {
                    CTBlip blip = blipFill.getBlip();
                    if (blip.getEmbed()!=null) {
                        String relId = blip.getEmbed();

                        // is this the one we want?
                        if (relId.equals(ird.imageRelId)) {
                            Part part = slidePart.getRelationshipsPart().getPart(relId);
                            try {
                                BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = (BinaryPartAbstractImage)part;
                                // you'll need to ensure that you replace like with like,
                                // ie png for png, not eg jpeg for png!
                                imagePart.setBinaryData(ird.replacementImageBytes);
                            } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
                                System.out.println(part.getClass().getName());
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(relId + " isn't a match for this replacement. ");                            
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No a:blip/@r:embed");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n saving .. \n\n");
        String outputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/OUT_VariableReplace.pptx";
        presentationMLPackage.save(new java.io.File(outputfilepath));

        System.out.println("\n\n done .. \n\n");


    }

    static class ImageReplacementDetails {

        int slideIndex;

        String imageRelId;

        byte[] replacementImageBytes;

    }


    static class SlidePicFinder extends CallbackImpl {

        List<org.pptx4j.pml.Pic> pics = new ArrayList<org.pptx4j.pml.Pic>();

        public List<Object> apply(Object o) {

            if (o instanceof org.pptx4j.pml.Pic) {
                pics.add((org.pptx4j.pml.Pic) o);
                System.out.println("added pic");
            }
            return null;
        }

    }


    }
```

Comment: You rock always! Really you are an God of Docx4j! Saved me! Really thanks.The image replacement worked like miracle. Its all your hardwork and mind!. Thanks Thanks